# combine two .caf files

Tags: iphone, caf

I have used below code to combine two .caf files.

```
NSMutableData *datas = [NSMutableData alloc];
NSData *data1 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path1];
NSData *data2 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path2];
NSLog(@"file1 size  : %d", [data1 length]);
NSLog(@"file2 size : %d", [data2 length]);
[datas appendData:data1];
[datas appendData:data2];
NSLog(@"file3 size  : %d", [datas length]);
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:combinedPath contents:datas attributes:nil];
```

Problem is; I can able to combine two files. But when I try to play the combined file, it is playing only the first file content.

Please help me to resolve it.

Thanks.

Comment: Somebody help me to resolve this issue...

Comment: Is there any way to append two audio files ?

Comment: I have tried with .mp3 files. Above mention code is working fine. If it is some other format, it is not working. I don't have idea to do for some other format (eg: .mp4, .wav, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution;

I have used Audio Queue Services to do this process.

[Click here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/AudioQueueReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005117) for documentation.

Comment: Could you please explain what you did with the Audio Queue Services?

Comment: We would appreciate if you can put some sample code by which achieved this. Thanks!