# Combining two .caf files on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, avfoundation

I've looked and looked for an answer, but can't seem to find one. Lots have asked, but none have gotten answers. I have an app that records audio using AVAudioRecorder. Now I just want to merge two or more recordings into one file that can be sent out via email. Does anyone have any clue as to how this can be done?

([This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4050192/combine-two-caf-files) suggests using something called Audio Service Queues, but I don't know anything about that)

Comment: Or if anyone knows how to combine two .wav files, that would be helpful also..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not quite as easy as you would think. I used the [AVFoundation framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/AVFoundationPG.pdf) to do exactly what you're asking about to create [iAmRingtones](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/iamringtones/id416200880?mt=8). It required creating AVAssets from the audio files and setting up an AVExportSession. The end result was great, but it certainly took a bit of work. Here's more or less how we created the export functionality in our app:

```
- (void) setUpAndAddAudioAtPath:(NSURL*)assetURL toComposition:(AVMutableComposition *)composition {

    AVURLAsset *songAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:assetURL options:nil];  

    AVMutableCompositionTrack *track = [composition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
    AVAssetTrack *sourceAudioTrack = [[songAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0];

    NSError *error = nil;
    BOOL ok = NO;

    CMTime startTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0, 1);
    CMTime trackDuration = songAsset.duration;
    CMTime longestTime = CMTimeMake(848896, 44100); //(19.24 seconds)
    CMTimeRange tRange = CMTimeRangeMake(startTime, trackDuration);

    //Set Volume
    AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters *trackMix = [AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters audioMixInputParametersWithTrack:track];
    [trackMix setVolume:0.8f atTime:startTime];
    [audioMixParams addObject:trackMix];

    //Insert audio into track
    ok = [track insertTimeRange:tRange ofTrack:sourceAudioTrack atTime:CMTimeMake(0, 44100) error:&error];
}
```

The above method gets called twice (once for each audio track) from the following method:

```
- (void) exportAudio {

    AVMutableComposition *composition = [AVMutableComposition composition];
    audioMixParams = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:nil];

    //Add Audio Tracks to Composition
    NSString *URLPath1 = pathToYourAudioFile1;
    NSURL *assetURL1 = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:URLPath1];
    [self setUpAndAddAudioAtPath:assetURL1 toComposition:composition];

    NSString *URLPath2 = pathToYourAudioFile2;
    NSURL *assetURL2 = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:URLPath2];
    [self setUpAndAddAudioAtPath:assetURL2 toComposition:composition];

    AVMutableAudioMix *audioMix = [AVMutableAudioMix audioMix];
    audioMix.inputParameters = [NSArray arrayWithArray:audioMixParams];

    //If you need to query what formats you can export to, here's a way to find out
    NSLog (@"compatible presets for songAsset: %@",
            [AVAssetExportSession exportPresetsCompatibleWithAsset:composition]);

    AVAssetExportSession *exporter = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc]
                                  initWithAsset: composition
                                  presetName: AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A];
    exporter.audioMix = audioMix;
    exporter.outputFileType = @"com.apple.m4a-audio";
    NSString *fileName = @"someFilename";
    NSString *exportFile = [[util getDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingFormat: @"/%@.m4a", fileName];    

    // set up export 
    myDeleteFile(exportFile);
    NSURL *exportURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:exportFile];
    exporter.outputURL = exportURL; 

    // do the export
    [exporter exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
            int exportStatus = exporter.status;
            switch (exportStatus) {
                case AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed: 
                    NSError *exportError = exporter.error;
                    NSLog (@"AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed: %@", exportError);
                    break;

                case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted: NSLog (@"AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted"); break;
                case AVAssetExportSessionStatusUnknown: NSLog (@"AVAssetExportSessionStatusUnknown"); break;
                case AVAssetExportSessionStatusExporting: NSLog (@"AVAssetExportSessionStatusExporting"); break;
                case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCancelled: NSLog (@"AVAssetExportSessionStatusCancelled"); break;
                case AVAssetExportSessionStatusWaiting: NSLog (@"AVAssetExportSessionStatusWaiting"); break;
                default:  NSLog (@"didn't get export status"); break;
    }
}];

    // start up the export progress bar
    progressView.hidden = NO;
    progressView.progress = 0.0;
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1
                                 target:self
                               selector:@selector (updateExportProgress:)
                               userInfo:exporter
                                repeats:YES];

}
```

Comment: how can I export it as .caf file instead of .m4a file?

Comment: exporter.outputFileType = AVFileTypeCoreAudioFormat; //.caf

Answer (score 1):

How to merge any number of Audio Files sequentially whose path is contained by an array called as recordingsArray

```
# pragma mark  mergeRecording

- (void) mergeRecording
{
        AVMutableComposition *composition = [AVMutableComposition composition];
        [self buildSequenceComposition:composition];   //given Below 

        NSLog (@"compatible presets for songAsset: %@",[AVAssetExportSession exportPresetsCompatibleWithAsset:composition]);

        AVAssetExportSession *exporter = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset: composition presetName: AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A];
        exporter.outputFileType = @"com.apple.m4a-audio";

        //File Name

        NSString *recordingFileName = [self setRecordingFileName];
        self.recordingTimeLbl.text = @"00:00:00";
        NSString *exportFile = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingFormat: @"/%@.m4a", recordingFileName];

        // set up export 
        BOOL yes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:exportFile error:NULL];
        NSURL *exportURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:exportFile];
        exporter.outputURL = exportURL; 
        NSData *sound1Data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: exportURL];
        NSLog(@"Length %i",sound1Data.length);

        [exporter exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
            int exportStatus = exporter.status;
            switch (exportStatus) {
                case AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed: 
                    NSLog (@"AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed:");
                    break;

                case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted: NSLog (@"AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted"); break;
                case AVAssetExportSessionStatusUnknown: NSLog (@"AVAssetExportSessionStatusUnknown"); break;
                case AVAssetExportSessionStatusExporting: NSLog (@"AVAssetExportSessionStatusExporting"); break;
                case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCancelled: NSLog (@"AVAssetExportSessionStatusCancelled"); break;
                case AVAssetExportSessionStatusWaiting: NSLog (@"AVAssetExportSessionStatusWaiting"); break;
                default:  NSLog (@"didn't get export status"); break;
            }
        }];

        // start up the export progress bar
        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector (updateProgress:) userInfo:exporter repeats:NO];
}


- (NSString *) setRecordingFileName
{
    NSDate *todaysDate = [NSDate date];

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
    NSString *dateString11 = [dateFormat stringFromDate:todaysDate];

    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [gregorian components:(NSHourCalendarUnit  | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit) fromDate:todaysDate];
    NSInteger hour = [dateComponents hour];
    NSInteger minute = [dateComponents minute];
    NSInteger second = [dateComponents second];
    [gregorian release];

    NSLog(@"Date: %@  \n Time : %@-%@-%@",dateString11,[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",hour],[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",minute],[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",second]);


    NSString *recordingFileName = @"Any Name";
    if(recordingFileName.length > 0)
    {
            recordingFileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@AND%@AND%@-%@-%@", recordingFileName, dateString11, [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",hour], [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",minute], [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",second]];
    }
    else
    {
            recordingFileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@AND%@-%@-%@",dateString11,[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",hour],[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",minute],[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",second]];
    }
    return recordingFileName;
}


- (void)updateProgress:(id)timer
{
    AVAssetExportSession *session;
    if([timer isKindOfClass:[NSTimer class]])
        session = (AVAssetExportSession *)[timer userInfo];
    else if([timer isKindOfClass:[AVAssetExportSession class]])
        session = timer;

    if (session.status == AVAssetExportSessionStatusExporting) 
    {

        NSArray *modes = [[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:NSDefaultRunLoopMode, UITrackingRunLoopMode, nil] autorelease];
        [self performSelector:@selector(updateProgress:) withObject:session afterDelay:0.5 inModes:modes];

    }
    else if(session.status == AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted)
    {
        NSLog(@"Exporting Ended");
        NSURL  *exportURL =  session.outputURL;
        NSData *sound1Data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: exportURL];
        NSLog(@"Length %i \n Path %@",sound1Data.length,exportURL);

        [self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
        self.activityIndicator.hidden = YES;
        NSLog(@"Merging Complete");

        for(int x = 0 ; x < [recordingsArray count] ; x++)
        {
                NSURL   *recordingPathUrl = [recordingsArray objectAtIndex:x];
                BOOL yes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:recordingPathUrl.relativePath error:NULL];
                if (yes) 
                {
                    NSLog(@"File Removed at Path %@",recordingPathUrl.relativePath);
                }
                else
                {
                    NSLog(@"Problem During Removal of Recording At Path %@",recordingPathUrl.relativePath);
                }

        }

        NSString *exportFile = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",exportURL];
        NSString *recordingFileName = [self setRecordingFileName];
        BOOL isInserted = [[DbFile sharedDatabase] insertRecordingDataIntoTable:recordingFileName recordingPath:exportFile];

        if(isInserted)
        {
            NSLog(@"Recording Inserted In Database");
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Recording Inserted In Database");
        }


         if([timer isKindOfClass:[NSTimer class]])
            [timer invalidate];

    }
    else if(session.status == AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed)
    {

            [self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
            NSLog(@"Recording Export Failed");

            UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Recording Export Failed" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
            [alertView show];
            [alertView release];

            if([timer isKindOfClass:[NSTimer class]])
                [timer invalidate];

    }
    else if(session.status == AVAssetExportSessionStatusCancelled)
    {

            [self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
            NSLog(@"Recording Export Cancelled");

            UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Recording Export Cancelled" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
            [alertView show];
            [alertView release];
            if([timer isKindOfClass:[NSTimer class]])
                [timer invalidate];
    }
}


- (void) buildSequenceComposition:(AVMutableComposition *)composition
{
    AVMutableCompositionTrack *audioTrack1 = [composition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio 
                                                                      preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
    CMTime nextClipStartTime = kCMTimeZero;

    for(NSURL * view in recordingsArray)
    {
        AVURLAsset* audioAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:view options:nil];
        CMTimeRange timeRangeInAsset;
        timeRangeInAsset = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, [audioAsset duration]);

        AVAssetTrack *clipVideoTrack = [[audioAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0];
        [audioTrack1 insertTimeRange:timeRangeInAsset ofTrack:clipVideoTrack atTime:nextClipStartTime error:nil];
        nextClipStartTime = CMTimeAdd(nextClipStartTime, timeRangeInAsset.duration);
    }
}
```