# Merge an Audio File with Two Video Files iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, xcode, audio, video, avmutablecomposition

I am wondering how I would combine a given audio file with two video files. I am stuck when it comes to combining the audio but the video is fine, here is what I have done so far

```
- (IBAction)MergeAndSave:(id)sender{
    if(firstAsset !=nil && secondAsset!=nil){
        [ActivityView startAnimating];
        //Create AVMutableComposition Object.This object will hold our multiple AVMutableCompositionTrack.
        AVMutableComposition* mixComposition = [[AVMutableComposition alloc] init];

        //VIDEO TRACK
        AVMutableCompositionTrack *firstTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
        [firstTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, firstAsset.duration) ofTrack:[[firstAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];

        AVMutableCompositionTrack *secondTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
        [secondTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, secondAsset.duration) ofTrack:[[secondAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:firstAsset.duration error:nil];

        //AUDIO TRACK
        if(audioAsset==nil){

            NSURL* musicFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                                       pathForResource:@"click"
                                                       ofType:@"caf"]];

            AVMutableCompositionTrack *click = [[AVMediaTypeAudio] initWithContentsOfURL:musicFile error:nil];
            [click insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, CMTimeAdd(firstAsset.duration, secondAsset.duration))
                                ofTrack:[[audioAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];


                   }
```

as you can see my code for the audio doesn't work at all

Comment: I've seen a tutorial of Raywenderlich which mergétwo videôandnyou can put a audiofile... Did you seen it? It may help you.

Comment: @Larme yes i have seen it :) but i want to use a dedicated audio file and not one from the ipod library

Comment: I guess that the difference is just the music you load: how to get it.

Comment: yes , but i have tried different code and havent been able to come up with a solution so i turned to you guy hoping yous could help

Answer (score 1):

Change Type of audioAsset to AVURLAsset instead of AVAsset
... hope it works

if not try this... [How can I overlap audio files and combine for iPhone in Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12628554/how-can-i-overlap-audio-files-and-combine-for-iphone-in-xcode)

Comment: i solved it
            
            AVMutableCompositionTrack *AudioTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
       
        AVURLAsset *mixAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"file" ofType:@"wav"]] options:nil];
        
            [AudioTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, CMTimeAdd(firstAsset.duration, secondAsset.duration)) ofTrack:[[mixAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:audioAsset.duration error:nil];

Comment: changing the type had nothing to do with making the code work , the solution was the URLAssetWithURL and  tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio