# Iphone: Audio Asset track not found when audio is created as a file, runtime in application

Tags: iphone, ios, avmutablecomposition

When I select audio as asset,I noticed Audio Asset track not found in selected asset. That "**audio is created runtime as a file**"(means created in application and saved in document directory).

I have used the code from link below ... its work when audio is selected as resources in project
but not in my case (**MY CASE: AUDIO IS CREATED IN APP AS FILE AND SAVED IN DOC. DIR.**)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12630437/1328096

Answer (score 0):

You can use this statement to check the sound of video

```
if([[songAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] firstObject]==NULL)
{
    NSLog(@"Sound is not Present");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Sound is Present");
    //You will initalise all things
    AVAssetTrack *sourceAudioTrack = [[songAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0];

}
```