# Play multiple audio at one same time

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, audio, avfoundation

My client wants to create an app in which user can play 4 audio at once and then start start any audio and then record them as one file.

I have not worked on audio/video apps so i want to know that is that possible in ios sdk?

How many audio file can be played at same time?

Comment: That depends on the API you are using. There are MANY. OpenAL, MediaPlayer, CoreAudio,...

Answer (score 2):

You can play many musics at the same time using [AVAudioSession](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/Configuration/Configuration.html).

```
UInt32 allowMixing = true;
AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryMixWithOthers, sizeof(allowMixing), &allowMixing);
```

Comment: so, it means we can play 4 audio at same time and then record 4 audio to make it one right?

Comment: I've never made any recording (but I'm sure you will find this in the doc :)), but I've use it to play different audio track at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

You can play multiple audio file with this code

```
NSString *songA = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"songA" ofType:@"mp3"];
NSError *soundError = nil;
self.player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:songA] error:&soundError];
if(self.player == nil)
    NSLog(@"%@",soundError);
else
{
    [self.player setDelegate:self];
    [self.player setVolume:0.75];
    [self.player play];
}

NSString *songB = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"songB" ofType:@"mp3"];
soundError = nil;
self.player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:songB] error:&soundError];
if(self.player == nil)
    NSLog(@"%@",soundError);
else
{
    [self.player setDelegate:self];
    [self.player setVolume:0.25];
    [self.player play];
}
```

To marge more than one audio file you can use ans from this question [Combining two .caf files on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7656512/combining-two-caf-files-on-iphone)